# Is having a channel buffer size greater than 0 essential for certain types of user generated events?

Tags: clojurescript, core.async

If you look at the code for the [async webinar](https://github.com/cognitect/async-webinar/blob/master/src/webinar/core.cljs) you will see that some channels are created with size 1, but most are size 0.

Size 1 seems to be used where two events could arrive at exactly the same time (where there is more than one source) or the events could be coming in very rapidly. For instance with a `EventType.KEYDOWN` event a user can hold the key down to rapidly generate events, whereas with a `EventType.CLICK` event from one button there is going to be a definite pause between events as the key does up and down again.

Is the purpose behind `(chan 1)` rather than `(chan)` just to make the demo 'less clunky', the effects smoother? Would what he is demonstrating still essentially work if all the channels had buffer size 0? Is the reasoning machine speed dependent - i.e. `(chan 1)` is there mainly for the benefit of people with slow machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a chan without a buffer, any puts to that chan will park until there is a corresponding take. Using a chan with buffer 1 lets the 'putter' continue running until it comes to make a second put. At that point it will park until someone takes from the buffer.

To give a concrete example, if the putting state machine (go block or thread) needs to run some side effect after a value is put on the channel but before it may have been processed by the receiving state machine, then you should use a buffer of one.

The choice between using a buffer of 1 or 0 of not should not be machine dependent (I think?), it will depend on the logical nature of the core.async state machines you've created, and whether two state machines need to synchronise at some point (`(chan 0)`), or if they can work more independently (`(chan 1)`).